# phase drop and now appliances dead

Tags: electrical, appliances

A few weeks back I started getting intermittent outages without breakers tripping.  It would self resolve after some time.  During one outage I was eventually able to troubleshoot and found that exactly half my panel was out.  I called the utility company and they came out next day and found a bad connection at their pole on one of the drops to my house.

As soon as they fixed that, I noticed oddities at my oven, beverage fridge and main fridge.  In the past week the beverage fridge and main fridge controls completely died.  Could this be related to the bad phase on the drop?  If so, what would be the right way to describe this to my insurer?

Edit: When the utility came out to check the connection, they found the drop with the bad connection had "low voltage".  I don't recall getting a number at that time.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you lose a phase, or did you lose neutral?

Comment: Power company may be at fault.And have to replace broken items.  They should be in charge to the meter.  Post better location and maybe someone in area  has advice.  I have run into this  many times and homeowner was taken  care of .

Answer (score 1):

Before you do that, try turning off the breakers to these devices, wait a couple of minutes, and turn them back on. The re-application of the lost leg when it was still connected to the other one may have set off some internal protective features that need to be powered down to reset.

Comment: Thanks. We're a few weeks out from the power company resolving. The beverage fridge completely died and I replaced the control and thermostat and it's back running. The main fridge is completely dead, confirmed the control board is fried (visibly burned) today. It'd been fluctuating in temperature since the power issues.

Comment: @user102382 Ah!  "Turn it off and turn it on again" is always a good thing to try (it's so cheap, and it *might* work - hence upvote), but it's not going to fix "visibly burnt". :-(